# How can I access values from the 'self' dictionary through iteration?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, self

I don't know how to effectively word my question, but I'll try my best. I want to be able to use a 'for' statement to iterate through a dictionary and access previously-made 'self' items. Like I said, hard to word the question.

I have found that I can use exec() to do it, but I had been told not to use exec() unless absolutely necessary. Also, I realize what this example does is technically useless, but it's a very simplified version of what I need.

```py
global counter
counter = 0
class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stuff = ["foo","bar","fooest","barest"]
        for i in self.stuff:
            self.process(i)
        self.printAll()

    def process(self,i):
        global counter
        counter += 1
        self.__dict__.update({"ex{}".format(counter):i})

    def printAll(self):
        global counter
        while counter > 0:
            exec("print(self.ex{})".format(counter))
            counter -= 1
GUI()
```

This does work; printAll(self) does print self.ex1 thru ex4. Is there a way to do it without exec()?. Please help!

Comment: Just use a container, don't dynamically add attributes, or if you absolutely must, use `getattr` and `setattr`.

Comment: Thanks, it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
global counter
counter = 0
class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stuff = ["foo","bar","fooest","barest"]
        for i in self.stuff:
            self.process(i)
        self.printAll()

    def process(self,i):
        global counter
        counter += 1
        self.__dict__.update({"ex{}".format(counter):i})

    def printAll(self):
        global counter
        while counter > 0:
            print(eval("self.ex{}".format(counter)))
            counter -= 1
GUI()
```

I hope this is suitable in your case

Comment: Mark as approve @Cryden

Comment: Sorry, didn't know I had to do that. My bad!